# how to show each user's uploaded picture to be present at navbar with django?

Tags: django

How do I serve the user's uploaded picture to him when he is logged in using Django?
what should I code inside the `src` attribute in html tags?

views.py:

```
def user_login(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app_1:home_page'))
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Time Out')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('invalid username or password')

 return render(request, 'app_1/login.html')
```

I have used Django's built in User model for the job with another model called `UserInfo` that has an attribute with an `OneToOne(User)` value ... I just don't know how to reference each user's picture ... please help me ...

Answer (score 0):

Inside the views, type:

```
user = UserInfo.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

Pass this user in the context, like this:

```
return render(request, 'TEMPLATE.html', { 'userinfo': user, }
```

Then inside the template, use `<image src="{{userinfo.image(or whatever else you've named the model that contains the image).url}}"></image>`

 Also, make sure you have the pillow module installed. That is important for this to work.

Put the context in the view associated with this url: ('app_1:home_page')

Comment: Muhammad Mashood thank you for your response .. but there is a slight problem ...
i'm using   (( return(HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(.....)) for returning to the template as if a user is logged in ... where do i put the context  dictionary than ?